# Mapping view for records with common values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with registrations, like this:

```
id  name  email            phone   
1   Jim   jim@gmail.com    111  
2   Jim   jim@hotmail.com  111  
3   Fred  fred@gmail.com   222   
4   Fred  fred@gmail.com   222
5   Adam  adam@gmail.com   333
```

Now I need to find all distinct people that have signed up and can do that through the email OR phone value. I want to have a table/view for the mapping. How can I get a similar result as shown below, based on the example table above?

```
person_id  registration_id   
1          1  
1          2
2          3
2          4
3          5
```

Note, there's no need for the id values to be exactly like that. I would be fine with re-using values from the registrations table or generate ids differntly.

Comment: What if a person registered twice, each time with a different email and different phone number?

Comment: In that case I'm fine with not being able to map it automatically.

Comment: What is person_id and registration_id in output. How it is related to specified table?

Comment: @seahawk: "person_id" is just a generated value representing a person (in the example an incremental int, but that's not a requirement) and is the value that maps multiple registrations together. "registration_id" is an existing id of the first table.

Comment: @Gustav : I guess you over-engineered the requirement. It can be achieved by simple query. Kindly refer my answer.

Comment: @seahawk: You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved by a simple query:

```
select min(a.id) as person_id,b.id as registration_id 
from
registrations a
join registrations b on ((a.email=b.email or a.phone=b.phone) and a.id<=b.id)
group by b.id
```

Kindly verify the result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61bd/11

Comment: @gustav I've upvoted this answer.. but is this what you really want? my answer returns exactly the results shown above (last row is 3, 5) while this answer returns (5, 5) - is it fine for you? If you don't mind having gaps just use this answer as it's simpler :)

Comment: @fthiella Yes, this solution is what I'm going to use. It wasn't clear in the question to begin with that gaps are ok, but it's definitely ok. Your answer is more exact though, but it's not a requirement to get results exactly like the example. I appreciate both of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the first person_id (based on same r1.phone or r1.email) for every registration id:

```
SELECT
  MIN(r2.id) AS person_id,
  r1.id AS registration_id
FROM
  registrations r1 LEFT JOIN registrations r2
  ON r1.email=r2.email OR r1.phone=r2.phone
GROUP BY
  r1.id
```

Now we just have to give a rank, but MySQL does not support it natively and we have to use a query with variables:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN @l = min_person_id THEN @r
    WHEN @l := min_person_id THEN @r := @r +1
  END AS person_id,
  registration_id
FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(r2.id) AS min_person_id,
    r1.id AS registration_id
  FROM
    registrations r1 LEFT JOIN registrations r2
    ON r1.email=r2.email OR r1.phone=r2.phone
  GROUP BY
    r1.id
) s, (SELECT @r := 0, @l := NULL) r
ORDER BY
  min_person_id
```

Plese see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61bd/3).

Comment: That only works when the registrations are in order, right?
Check this fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d61bd/1

registration_id 4 should be mapped to the same person_id as registration_id 1.

Comment: @Gustav I've updated my answer, fixed the order: `ORDER BY min_person_id` if you really want the results to be ordered by registration_id you need to `SELECT * FROM (query above) AS s ORDER BY registration_id`